# What should i use to access the data in different .JS file from a .JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am working on a project where i need to access the json response results into another .js files.

In this code i am getting json data in result variable in function handleLogin. How could i export this variable and import/call in different .js file to use the data of result variable. I cannot export this function handLogin cause its been called onSubmit in html code.
Like this result JSON data contains some data like name age and various other parameters and i want it to display it in a different .js file how could i do that. How could i retrieve this variable.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";



class Login extends React.Component{
    
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row ces-login-bg">
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-6 login-intro-container">
                        <img alt = "" className="ces-logo" src="https://www.cesltd.com/img/ces-logo.png"/>
                        <h1 className="timesheet-head">Timesheets</h1>
                        <p className="intro-text">a comprehensive solution for your timesheets, holidays and leaves</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-6 ">
                        <form className="form-container" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                            <h1 className="login-heading">Login</h1>
                            <div className="email-label ">
                                <label className="label-element">Email</label>
                                <input className="input-element" type ="email" id = 'email' name="email" required/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="password-label ">
                                <label className="label-element">Password</label>
                                <input className="input-element" type="password" id = "password" name="password" required/>
                            </div>
                            {/* <p className="error-message">Invalid login credentials</p> */}
                            <button type ="submit" className="button-container" >
                                <p className="login-button">Login</p>
                                {/* <i className="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i> */}
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


async function handleLogin(event){


        
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let payload = {
        "params":{"db":"dev02","login":event.target.email.value, "password":event.target.password.value}
        }
        let result = await axios.post('http://dev02.abcltd.net:8020/mobile/session/authenticate', payload);
    try{
        if (result.data.result.message.toLowerCase() === 'success') {
            
            window.open('/Timesheets','_self');
    
        }

    }
    catch{
        alert('Invalid Email or Password')
    }
}



export default Login
```

Expecting to export this result data and import it in different .js file

Comment: I think useContext may solve your problem.

Comment: okay, I'll have a look into that topic. Also, do you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: the other alternative is to fetch data in the parent component and pass it through its children using props

Comment: well, I am not using any parent component both are independent components.

Comment: You must have a parent component somewhere otherwise what renders those two components?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).